# How to implement spring boot Redis multi tenancy?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, multi-tenant

I am facing issues while creating a Multitenant application using spring boot and Redis. I have used the same solution which is mentioned in [How to implement multitenancy for Redis in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661914/how-to-implement-multitenancy-for-redis-in-spring-boot/59676369#59676369). But it didn't work. Is there a different way to implement Redis multitenancy with Spring boot.

Comment: `But it didn't work.` -> What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried below code given on this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661914/how-to-implement-multitenancy-for-redis-in-spring-boot/59676369#59676369

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by adding a check if the data source not available in the cache then pull from the required source and create a connection. Also changed calling afterPropertiesSet() explicitly which is mentioned in [How to implement multitenancy for redis in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661914/how-to-implement-multitenancy-for-redis-in-spring-boot/59676369#59676369)